# Fastest way to traverse arbitary depth tree for deletion?

Tags: c++, tree-traversal, depth-first-search

For my own exercises I'm writing an XML-parser. To fill the tree I use a normal `std::stack` and push the current node on top after making it a child of the last top-node (should be depth-first?). So I now do the same for deletion of the nodes, and I want to know if there's a faster way.
Current code for deletion:

```
struct XmlNode{
    // ignore the rest of the node implementation for now
    std::vector<XmlNode*> children_;
};
XmlNode* root_ = new XmlNode;

// fill root_ with child nodes...
// and then those nodes with child nodes and so fort...

std::stack<XmlNode*> nodes_;
nodes_.push(root_);
while(!nodes_.empty()){
    XmlNode* node = nodes_.top();
    if(node->children_.size() > 0){
        nodes_.push(node->children_.back());
        node->children_.pop_back();
    }else{
        delete nodes_.top();
        nodes_.pop();
    }
}
```

Works totally fine but it kinda looks slow. So is there any faster / better / more common way to do this?

Comment: "kinda looks slow" is not an acceptable description for the performance of an algorithm. Have you profiled the code and see how fast it goes? Do you have hard data?

Comment: @Xeo: Why are you avoiding recursion? Is there really a risk of SO?

Comment: Can have a tighter loop inside your `if (...size() > 0)`, pushing child nodes with children onto the stack / deleting those without children bypassing the stack, then `clear()`.  (Some people recommend `!...children_.empty()`, as empty()'s constant time for all containers so one less maintenance point if changing container, but `size()` is constant time for stacks anyway).

Comment: @Mehrdad: he did say performance was his concern... recursion's very likely slower as well as the potential SO risk.

Comment: @Tony: I hadn't heard of recursion being slow... would you mind explaining why? (Is it because of potential page faults?)

Comment: @Mehrdad: function calls are such a crucial part of program execution that they've been highly optimised and the exact overheads vary from CPU to CPU and depending on the compiler and calling conventions, but generally it can involve pushing some registers onto the stack as well as the function return address and arguments, moving the stack frame registers, undoing all that afterwards.  That's overwhelmingly likely to be a bigger operation than a single pointer stack push/pop and iteration.  As you say, the faster-growing execution stack will fit less well in cache, page fault more....

Comment: @Tony: But there's just as much memory access here (with the stack), and register operations are pretty negligible... assuming your tree depth isn't great enough to trigger a guard page, is the difference actually statistically significant?

Comment: @Mehrdad: "register operations are pretty negligible"... registers may be fast to use, but when stored they use just as much stack memory as any other same-sized data, so rather than "just as much memory" it's probably an order of magniture worse.  Still, the program stack avoids risk of resizing the heap stack, which is a benefit for large structures.  "assuming your tree depth isn't great enough"... how large is a typical XML document... very app specific.  When Q asks specifically re performance, what's significant is for him to say.  Benchmarking required, but iteration's typically faster.

Comment: @Tony: Hm... I guess I can't really argue for or against either I guess, since I haven't benchmarked it. But thanks for the info. :)

Comment: @Mehrdad: FYI - just wrote a simple benchmark for recursive vs iterative factorial function; under gcc 3.4.6 with -O2, iteration's over 40 times faster. Impl: `return n == 1 ? 1 : n * factorial__recursion(n - 1);`. Might get better if written to ensure tail recursion optimisation, but that's the obvious way. 70* faster under v4.5.2.  Cheers.

Comment: @Tony: Wow, all right; thanks! (Edit: Wait -- how deep was the factorial? Did it trigger page faults?)

Comment: @Mehrdad: very deep - would have triggered page faults.  For 1000! at -O2 with GCC 4.5.2, the recursive version is actually benchmarking ~15 times faster... the tail recursion optimisation and goodness knows what others must have kicked in :-).  Might not work for a more complex function body, but then the recursion vs iteration overheads become less significant too.  Shows how important it is to benchmark your exact situation! :-)

Comment: @Tony: Making it very deep is very unfair, unless your tree is also 1000 levels deep. In a semi-balanced binary search tree, for example, that would mean around 2^1000 elements (more or less). So unless you're actually going to be working with data that big, your benchmark isn't really benchmarking anything practical. (I wasn't saying you should do linear traversals with recursion [unless your compiler does tail recursion]; I was saying you should do **tree** traversal with recursion, and in that case, they should have very similar performances. **Big** difference!)

Comment: @Tony: [Here](http://ideone.com/asGRi)'s a *fair* comparison; on my computer, recursion is **faster** by a factor of 3. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't go out of your way to do iteratively what can be easily done recursively,** unless you can *prove* that the recursive version is either insufficient (e.g. stack overflows) or slower (which won't happen unless you start overflowing your stack, forcing the OS to either expand it or crash you).

In other words, in general, use iteration for linear structures, and recursion for tree structures.

[Compared to recursion](http://ideone.com/asGRi), an iterative method was around 3 times slower on my machine. If you can be sure that your XML depth won't exceed a few hundred nestings (which I've never seen inside real-world XML documents), then recursion won't be a problem.

---

To iterate is human; to recurse, divine. :)